# Draw image on AWT Canvas

Tags: java, image, canvas, awt

I'm trying to draw an image on an AWT Canvas.

The only line I've got this far is:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
```

I'm not sure which method to use to add an image to the canvas now... I tried `createImage()` but didn't know how to continue with the ImageProducer...

Maybe someone's got a little hint for me here?

Comment: You try creating image using createImage with null ImageProducer

Comment: Have you done any research? There's thousands of question on So about this topic. Google probably has millions. Sure someone could give you an answer, but it would be  no better than a repeat of all the other other posts. Why don't you search, and if you actually try something and it doesn't work, then post an MCVE. Not that I'm too lazy to give you an answer, but you actually doing some research will help you out in the long run. While you're at it, you may want to do some research on AWT vs. Swing. Happy Searching ;-)

Comment: @peeskillet: Sure, I did! Otherwise i wouldn't have asked ;) Unfortunately I'm forced to use AWT due to my environment (I'm doing notifications with Mylyn).

Answer (score 4):

You have several ways to do this. If you don't want to create a subclass of `Canvas`, add this line (where `img` is a subclass `java.awt.Image`):

```
canvas.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0,0, null);
```

This will draw your Image to position 0,0 on the Canvas. If you create a subclass of canvas, overwrite the `paint`-Method:

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0,0, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is several steps how to draw image on the canvas.

Make your own canvas on a frame object.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display {
    private JFrame jframe;
    private static Canvas canvas;
    private String title;
    private int width, height;

    public Display(String tuade, int rong, int dai) {
        this.title = tuade;
        this.width = dai;
        this.height = rong;
        initCanvas();
    }

    private void initCanvas() {

        jframe = new JFrame(title);
        jframe.setSize(width, height);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        jframe.add(canvas);
        jframe.pack();

    }

    public Canvas getCanvas() {

        if(canvas == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Canvas is null");
            return null;
        }

        return canvas;
    }
}
```

Then, draw an image on the Display class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class DrawImageOnCavas implements Runnable {
    private Display Display;
    private Thread t;
    private boolean running;
    public int dai, rong;
    private String tuade;
    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;
    private BufferedImage testImage;

    public DrawImageOnCavas(String tuade, int dai, int rong) {
        this.dai = dai;
        this.rong = rong;
        this.tuade = tuade;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();
        System.err.println("run..." + running);
        while (running) {
            //System.err.println("run..." + running);
            tick();
            render();
        }
        //stop();
    }

    private void render() {
        bs = Display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();

        if (bs == null) {
            System.out.println("bs is null....");
            Display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }


        g = Display.getCanvas().getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(testImage, 20, 20, null);
    }

    private void tick() {

    }

    private static final class ImageLoader
    {

        static BufferedImage loadImage(String fileName)
        {
            BufferedImage bi = null;
            //System.err.println("....setimg...." + fileName);

            try {
                bi = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName)); 

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Image could not be read");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            return bi;
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        Display = new Display(tuade, dai, rong);
        testImage = ImageLoader.loadImage("texture/Lilong.png");
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (running) return;
        running = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (!running)
            return;
        running = false;
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The entry method is as follows,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   DrawImageOnCavas game = new DrawImageOnCavas("draw image", 400, 400);
   game.start();

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
getImage()
drawImage()
```

There are many methods of drawing graphics in java.[it will get you started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/)